# Extension of a Partition

Tags: linux

My question is, suppose I have a partition by the name sda1 of 5GB size in the virtual hard disk of size 10  GB. I have mounted /home to this partition (sda1). Now, this partition is full. Is is possible to extend the size of this partition? without using LVM concept and keeping my data intact.
 How can I?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You will first need to unmount it and increase the partition size, using something like `fdisk`, then run `resize2fs`. You can find many tutorials on how to do this online, for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition

Comment: Alright, thankyou for your time.